# How can I remove SCM file status from the project drawer in Textmate 2

Tags: git, textmate, textmate2

Can I remove these status icons from the files in my project drawer?  (i.e. the red x's and green +'s in the image below) I tried removing some SCM bundles from Textmate but that didn't do the trick...

I'm using the latest version of Textmate 2

[image: My project drawer where files have SCM status]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add `scmStatus = false` to your TextMate properties file (`~/.tm_properties`), that should do the trick.

*Source:* [TextMate's Github issue #1051: "Disable SCM badges"](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/issues/1051).

Comment: Thanks! Note that this file does not exist by default, you have to create it (or at least I did).

Comment: Yes, or you can use `Library/Application Support/TextMate/Global.tmProperties` if you prefer.

Comment: There's also a project level version of this file, same name, in the root of you project folder. It can be created automatically with the bundle Avian Missing.