# Alert Symbol On Texmate File and Folder

Tags: textmate

Hi I'm new on TextMate.

What does it mean with these symbol on folders and files in TextMate? Is it a problem? How do I solve it?

[image: Untitled]

thank you,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They show you the current state of the files in your version control system (Git, subversion).

The symbols on your screenshot mean that those files are currently not tracked. There are various other symbols for deleted files, edited files and so on...

To "solve" it, you can select those files in the file browser, press ⌘Y for the Git menu and choose to commit them (assuming you have the Git bundle installed).

If you just want to disable the symbols, theres an answer for a tm_properties setting over here: [How can I remove SCM file status from the project drawer in Textmate 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620541/how-can-i-remove-scm-file-status-from-the-project-drawer-in-textmate-2)